Determine all $m \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $\forall a \in \mathbb{N}$ $gcd(m,a)=1$ and $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod m$
I tried using quadratic residues, but I couldn't get much further in determining what $m$ those are.
Additionally, Fermat's Little Theorem seems to be a special case rather than a general solution.

$a^2\equiv1\pmod m$ implies $\gcd(a,m)=1,$ so those,conditions are redundant.

Weird that neither "duplicate" is a duplicate. Is this supposed t9 be true for all $a?$

@ThomasAndrews yes, I improved the question. It should be true for all $a$

Honestly, I don't know how the "duplicated" questions could help me.

@OP if you seek the moduli $,m,$ such that $,a^2\equiv 1,$ for all $a$ coprime to $m$ then see the linked dupes for proof that it holds $\iff m\mid 24.,$  If that is not your question then please elaborate more precsely.

Direction $(\Rightarrow)$ is proved in the first dupe and direction $(\Leftarrow)$ is proved in the 2nd dupe. See also the many linked posts there for more on this FAQ.

The title is incorrect.   It's essentially nonsense.
